# Google App Engine - Node: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin'

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-admin

First time deploying a GAE app here, I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html (see node code section).

I ran

```
npm install firebase-admin --save
npm install request --save
```

on my machine, the package.json is here, but when I use `gcloud app deploy`, I get these logs when opening the app on my browser:

```
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]  module.js:471
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]      throw err;
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]      ^
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]  Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin'
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]      at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]      at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]      at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:1:78)
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-02-10 09:35:02 default[20170210t103151]      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]  module.js:471
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]      throw err;
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]      ^
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]  Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin'
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]      at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]      at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]      at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:1:78)
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-02-10 09:35:07 default[20170210t103151]      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]  module.js:471
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]      throw err;
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]      ^
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]  Error: Cannot find module 'serviceAccountKey.json'
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]      at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]      at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]      at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:7:22)
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-02-10 09:43:58 default[20170210t104151]      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]  module.js:471
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]      throw err;
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]      ^
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]  Error: Cannot find module 'serviceAccountKey.json'
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]      at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]      at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]      at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:7:22)
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-02-10 09:44:10 default[20170210t104151]      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-02-10 16:20:02 default[20170210t124920]  Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "connect ETIMEDOUT 74.125.202.84:443".
2017-02-10 16:20:02 default[20170210t124920]      at /app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:74:23
2017-02-10 16:20:02 default[20170210t124920]      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

How do I fix this ??

Comment: Got a similar problem, also have the "Cannot find module 'serviceAccountKey.json'. I have a feeling this has to do with the firebase-admin module.

Comment: Does the script work locally? Does it only fail when you deploy to GAE?

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm supposed to test it locally... Not a node expert (yet), can you guide me on how to do so ?

Comment: Anyone? I'd like to get this over with :)

Comment: Are you sure your package.json and your service account key file are actually getting deployed to GAE? It looks like they are not.

Comment: How do I check this?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solved this ?

Comment: Yeah, I switched to Heroku... Please tell me if you manage to get it working on GAE

Comment: Your package.json and serviceAccountKey.json files are definitely being omitted from the deployment, possible due to existing outside of the directory where your app.yaml is located. Can post a listing of the root level of your app directory? To test locally by the way, you can just do 'node app.js' (or whatever you've named your app's main .js file).

Comment: @warhost:
You need to give the full path JSON of the serviceAccountKey file, even you put the file in the same directory with the script.

For me is:
 `var serviceAccount = require('/Users/silviu/Ionic Projects/CD_Backend/service_account.json');`
instead of
 `var serviceAccount = require('service_account.json');`

Comment: @jacobawenger, or someone who knows... I have the same problem described. Could you please specify how to deploy the serviceAccountKey.json file? My app runs locally, but when I deploy I get the the error describe in the question.

Answer (score 44):

These issues seem to be caused by a misunderstanding of how `require()` paths work. You cannot use an absolute path because something like `require("/Users/username/somepath")` obviously won't exist on the remote machine when the app is deployed and the import will fail. Using `require("serviceAccountKey.json")` is going to look in *node_modules/serviceAccountKey.json* relative to the app directory.

If you want to load *serviceAccountKey.json* from the app's root directory, you would use `require("./serviceAccountKey.json")`. If it were in a subdirectory called *foo* under the root you'd use `require("./foo/serviceAccountKey.json")`. This also applies to loading modules in general such as `firebase-admin`.

The [NodeJS Modules documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) explains the `require()` mechanism in greater detail.

Comment: this is a very nicely explained answer. This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 4):

I could make a workaround on this proceeding like this:
(passing the serviceAccountkeyFile.json parameters inside app.js code):

```
let defaultAppConfig = {
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        type: "service_account",
        project_id: "txxxxxxxxxx",
        private_key_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        private_key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
        client_email: "firebaxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.gserviceaccount.com",
        client_id: "11111111111111111",
        auth_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        token_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        auth_provider_x509_cert_url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        client_x509_cert_url: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/jjjjjj.gserviceaccount.com"
    }),
    databaseURL: 'https://projectxxx.firebaseio.com/'
}

defaultApp = admin.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);
```

Comment: this way show me red underline with error Argument of type '{type:string}.... is not assignable to paramter of type

Comment: @AdirZoari, where in code this red underline is appearing? I can imagine that you can verify your lint component (jslint, eslint, etc.). If they are not perfectly and correctly configured, sometimes we have these behavior you mentioned...

Comment: you can see my issue I post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272165/firebase-import-service-throws-error

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? A typical message from it... If so, configure your lint properly. For instance, if you are using ESLINT, configure it properly.  The example I wrote above if from a Node.js file that is working perfectly.

Comment: It's recommended not to include secrets in your source code, in case it goes public on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem running `gcloud app deploy`

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-dev-server'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
```

I solved the issue moving the given dependency (wepack-dev-server) from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` in `package.json`.

In case somebody else has the same problem I suggest to have look at your dependencies in `package.json`. `dependencies` are required to run, `devDependencies` only to develop, e.g.: unit tests, Coffeescript to Javascript transpilation, minification,