# Where is or What is the serviceAccountKey.json is the node js sample of firebase realtime database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have downloaded the zip of `Firebase real-time database node.js sample` and navigate to the database section

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/tree/master/database

And I located to the `line 35` which has the following code

```
var serviceAccount = require('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');
```

But I was wondering where is/what is the serviceAccountKey.json?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a JSON file generated in the [Firebase Console](http://console.firebase.google.com/) (see [Add Firebase to your App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app)) containing credentials about your corresponding [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts).

Comment: They told me I can generate one in the setting

Answer (score 14):

1. `require('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')` means - call this file to be used in the file you are calling it
2. **serviceAccountKey.json** is a file that you have to generate
3. If you look at this page 'Add Firebase To Your App' https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup under 'Add Firebase to your app' - it says Navigate to the Service Accounts and generate a new private key, doing this will generate what will be your 'serviceAccountKey.json' file *after you rename it*
4. place that file in the directory of your choosing local to your cloud code directory, have a look at this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/42634321/2472466 for more insight into step 4

Answer (score 8):

How to download your serviceAccountKey.json file

1. Open Your firebase project
2. On the navigation drawer, select the project overview
3. Then select "Project settings"
4. On the new page, Select Service Accounts
5. Download file and store in a secured place.

Note: Do not commit this file to git or share it with unauthorized users.

Comment: This is the simplest answer

Answer (score 8):

Go to settings -> Service Account -> Generate New private key

That will download the required Json