# firebase import service throws error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using firebase functions and I want to initializeApp with service account key json into credential and I get the error

> Argument of type '{ "type": string; "project_id": string; "private_key_id": string; "private_key": string; "client_...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | ServiceAccount'.
>     Type '{ "type": string; "project_id": string; "private_key_id": string; "private_key": string; "client_...' has no properties in common with type 'ServiceAccount'.

my index.ts file

```
 import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import {serviceAccount} from './serviceAccount'

console.log(functions.config())
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL:functions.config().firebase
});

export const firestore = admin.firestore();
export const firebase = admin.database();
```

serviceAccount.ts

```
export const serviceAccount = {

    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "lxxxxxx",
    "private_key_id": "xxxxxx",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxx---END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "firebase-axxxxx-9b58b.iaxxxceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "xxxxx",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/xxxxx",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oxxxxn",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "clixxxxxx": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadataxxxxirebase-adminsdk-uxxxxxxrviceaccount.com"


}
```

the error in this line of code

```
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
```

Answer (score 45):

I've experienced this too. The solution is to bring the type `ServiceAccount` and cast to that type the whole object imported from that json file.

```
import firebase from 'firebase' 
import * as firebaseAdmin from 'firebase-admin' 
import firebaseConfig from '../firebaseConfig.json' 
import firebaseAccountCredentials from '../serviceAccountCredentials.json'

const serviceAccount = firebaseAccountCredentials as admin.ServiceAccount

firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: firebaseConfig.databaseURL 
});
```

Comment: I prefer the syntax 
`credential: admin.credential.cert( <ServiceAccount>serviceAccount ),`

Comment: what is the syntax called when you declare a variable with a = and then also use as syntax?  this is not working for me, "as" throws unexpected identifier

Comment: @Peege151 `as` is called type-assertion keyword

Answer (score 4):

I've had an issue like this. 
Try converting to JSON and back.
Like this:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(serviceAccount))),
  databaseURL: functions.config().firebase
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very experienced with TypeScript, but I think this will work as a temporary solution until someone proposes a better one.

```
let regularObj = {};
Object.assign(regularObj, serviceAccount);

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(regularObj),
  databaseURL: functions.config().firebase
});
```

Comment: works perfect for string content. 
JSON.parse(fileContent); //Just convert the string to JSON Object first
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple method, you just have give that import a type. In my case object.

```
import * as serviceAccount  from './service-account.json';
const credentialObject:object = serviceAccount;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have needed add "assert { type: "json" }" to import the credentials with no errors. Like this:

```
import serviceAccount from "./service-account.json" assert { type: "json" };

const params = {
    type: serviceAccount.type,
    projectId: serviceAccount.project_id,
    privateKeyId: serviceAccount.private_key_id,
    privateKey: serviceAccount.private_key,
    clientEmail: serviceAccount.client_email,
    clientId: serviceAccount.client_id,
    authUri: serviceAccount.auth_uri,
    tokenUri: serviceAccount.token_uri,
    authProviderX509CertUrl: serviceAccount.auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
    clientC509CertUrl: serviceAccount.client_x509_cert_url
}

initializeApp({ credential: cert(params)});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem and the way I fixed it was to keep how the .json file was generated when I created the key

serviceAccount.json

```
{
  "type": "",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "",
  "universe_domain": ""
}
```

---

then reference it in a variable using require,

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin/app";
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceaccount.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.cert(serviceAccount),
});
```

---

or you could use import and have it like this, but then you would have to set resolveJsonModule to true in the tsconfig.json

```
import * as serviceAccount from "./serviceaccount.json";

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.cert(serviceAccount as admin.ServiceAccount)
});
```